# How to animate a div over other divs if float left is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I have a parent div with a width of 100%, and 3 sub-divs with a width of 33.333333% each. All 3 divs are floated left so they align in one row.

I want to animate one of the 33.333333% div to 100% but what I want it to do is to go over the other 2 divs without it being pushed to the next row?

```
<div id="fullwidth">
    <div id="history" class="thirdwidth">
        <h1>Our History</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="now" class="thirdwidth">
        <h1>Now</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="whatwedo" class="thirdwidth">
        <h1>What We Do</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I do this?

See example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/y9qcd2wc/2/

Comment: You have to use absolute positioning instead of floats

Comment: You can style a child div using relative positioning like this: https://jsfiddle.net/y9qcd2wc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".thirdwidth").on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
html, body{margin:0; height:100%;}

.thirdwidth      {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  top:0;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s; -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
}
.thirdwidth.push0{left:0%;}
.thirdwidth.push1{left:33.333%;}
.thirdwidth.push2{left:66.333%;}

#history {background:red;}
#now     {background:green;}
#whatwedo{background:blue;}

.thirdwidth.active{z-index:1; left:0; width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullwidth">
  <div id="history" class="thirdwidth push0">
    <h1>Our History</h1>
    click to maximize, and click again to minimize
  </div>
  <div id="now" class="thirdwidth push1">
    <h1>Now</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="whatwedo" class="thirdwidth push2">
    <h1>What We Do</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best one out of all. Is there any chance I could hide a text when its not full width yet, but show the text after I click one of the 3 divs to make it full screen?